# How do I empty a slice in a RefMut<&mut [u8]>?

Tags: rust

If I wanted to "empty" a slice normally, I could do something like this:

```rust
let mut data: &[u8] = &[1, 2, 3];
data = &[];
```

But I'm using a library that returns a `RefMut<&mut [u8]>`, and if I try to reset it the same way:

```rust
let mut data: RefMut<&mut [u8]> = account.data.borrow_mut();
data = &[];
```

I get told I need:

```
expected struct `RefMut`, found `&[_; 0]`
```

I try something like this:

```rust
let mut data: RefMut<&mut [u8]> = account.data.borrow_mut();
let cleared: &mut [u8] = &mut [];
let c = RefCell::new(cleared);
data = c.borrow_mut();
```

But then c is dropped while still borrowed. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Instead of modifying the slice, how about shadowing it? `let data: &[u8] = &[1, 2, 3]; let data: &[u8] = &[];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the dereference operator to write back to the `RefCell`.

```rust
let refcell: RefCell<&[u8]> = RefCell::new(&[1, 2, 3]);
{
    let mut data = refcell.borrow_mut();
    *data = &[];
    // or equivalently, *refcell.borrow_mut() = &[];
}
println!("{:?}", refcell); // RefCell { value: [] }
```